# No Jar files included in .deb file

Tags: java, debian

I have created a debian source package for my java swing app that has .jar file and two lib/jar files. Three files (`.dsc`, `.orig.tar.xz`, `debian.tar.gz`) were generated as part of the debian source package. When I create the `.deb` file using:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

it gives the following error in install file:

cp: cannot stat debian/tmp/abc-1.0/xyz.jar: No such file or directory dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/abc-1.0/abc.jar debian/aspose/aspose-1.0/ returned code 1 make dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error status 2

Contents of install file:

```
aspose-1.0/Aspose.Examples.Launcher.jar 
aspose-1.0/lib/jsch-0.1.27.jar 
aspose-1.0/lib/org.eclipse.jgit-2.2.0.201212191850-r.jar
```

Following are the contents of my rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please add the output of `cat debian/*install`.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please answer.

Comment: Following is the error coming when i run the command:
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b 

cp: cannot stat ‘debian/tmp/aspose-1.0/Aspose.Examples.Launcher.jar’: No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/aspose-1.0/Aspose.Examples.Launcher.jar debian/aspose//aspose-1.0/ returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok，I think that you have not created debian folder.  The files which are install, rules and so on in debian folder are very important for creating deb package. So you should read debian official manual to learn how to do it.  As you said, you should generate a install file for installing .jar file.  Good luck.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please answer.